# NextJS page has grey bars

Tags: next.js

Trying to add a page in a nextjs app and got this:
[image]

hello.js:

```js
export default function Hello() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have just used create-next-app and made no other changes.

Comment: please share your code example

Comment: I have just used create-next-app and made no other changes.

Comment: Share your CSS file please. I had this problem, it depends on the browser. You have to reset some css body properties from what i remember